# How to set the range of the primary-key of django objects based on the foreign key range and is it advisable?

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have the below models:

```
class Author(model):
    name = CharField(...)

class Post(mode):
    author = ForeignKey(Author)
    title = CharField(...)
```

Suppose we have at most 100 authors. So the primary key of the autors would be in the range of 1 to 100
I want the primary keys of the post model be based on the primary key of the author of the post.

I mean, if the author's primary key is 34, then his/her posts primary keys be 34000001, 34000002, 34000003

is advisable to do this and how can I do it?

Comment: No. It is not advisable to treat the pk as anything other than an opaque value.

Comment: As Daniel says. And why would you want that?

Comment: If it is not advisable, I will not do it. My reason was having more control over the database. Besides not being advisable, this control is not worth its headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally not advisable and might tempt you to follow (or invent) antipatterns. If your goal is to be able to easily access a particular author's posts, for example, you would be safest using Django's normal ORM patterns. For example:

```
# models.py
class Author(model):
    name = CharField(...)

class Post(model):
    author = ForeignKey(Author, related_name='posts')
    title = CharField(...)
```

Then anywhere you want, you can...

```
sally = Author.objects.get(id=1)
sallys_posts = author.posts.all()
```

This would be much safer than things you might otherwise be tempted to do such as `Post.objects.filter(pk__startswith=sally.pk)` which would be something that I think would lead to a large number of bugs down the line, and would also mean that you miss out on a lot of normal pattern Django ORM benefits.